# Crossreferencing in xtext - also for native types

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to set up a xtext grammar that has the following characteristics.

Sketch(!):

```
Class:
    properties += Property*
;

Resource:
    properties += Property* 
;


Link :
    // no classes here, so no common for Resource and Class
    [Resource]  <-> [Resource]
;

BasicType:
    'int' | 'long'
;

Property:
    // this is not supported
    name ':' BasicType | [Resource] | [Class]

    // i tried
    // name ':' EObject
;
```

My question is:

How can i solve this situation, to crossreference a property type to 'Resource' or 'Class' or a BasicType?

I tried with EObject as BaseType and resolve the crossreferences in a custom ScopeProvider ,
but then i dont know how to use BasicTypes (int or long) as Type for properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you can introduce common supertypes by defining a rule that you dont call

```
Parent: Child1 | Child2
```

then you can reference only things that are defined somewhere else.
thus you have to define them explicitely or change the grammar

[XText entity example, primitive type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710059/xtext-entity-example-primitive-type/23711659#23711659)

Comment: Thanks. Your awnser provided valueable ints for me.